# Unable to get subsribe items in ion-select-options in mobile

Tags: ionic-framework, observable, ionic4

This is code in my html file

```
<ion-select>
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let gender of genderOptions" value="{{ gender }}">{{ gender }}
            </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

this is from my .ts file. I'm calling this in `constructor()`

```
this.httpService.getGenders().subscribe((genderArrObj: any) => {
  for (const i of genderArrObj) {
    this.genderOptions.push(i.gender);
   }
  }, err => console.log(err));
```

and the getGender() in my httpService file

```
getGenders() {
return this.http.get(`${serverUrl}masters/genders`);
}
```

I'm getting the list of genders in my browser(PC) but not in my mobile. I'm running it on [devapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.ionic.devapp&hl=en)

Comment: Do you maybe have CORS issues by calling the server from your mobile phone? This sounds for me like a connectivity problem on your mobile phone - because of  the fact that the request works in browser (desktop).

Comment: Yeah, at first I thought it was something with observable. But how I can send the request to localhost running on my desktop?

Comment: You should have your server running somewhere reachable for your client. Best solution would be to have a real server (not a desktop pc). But for tests / development you could open the ports on your desktop for the client requests and call the IP of your desktop instead of "localhost" from your client. But just do this for tests. Make sure that your client is in the same network as your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it async I think:

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let gender of genderOptions | async" value="{{ gender }}">{{ gender }}
        </ion-select-option>
```

It's a built in part of Angular:

- https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

  > The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but now I understand its a CORS issue, yet not know how to solve it.

Comment: People don't have much time to help. Make it easy for them to help you and either close this question or change it to ask for the help you really need.